# How to Upload Image Using Ajax - PHP

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, file-upload, upload

How can i upload Image/File Using Ajax ? Check Facebook Comments with Image **(Same as facebook)**.

Is there any possible way to do so ?

If there is a way than how can we **Move** that Selected Image File to our **Specified Images Directory**?

**Here is the HTML :**

```
<input name="image_src" type="file" id="image_src" />
```

Comment: uploadify comes to mind

Answer (score 0):

jQuery doesn't allow for uploading files using an AJAX request.

You could use the new HTML5 XmlHttpRequest object that allows you to upload files using an AJAX request. Checkout the following article containing detailed instructions and examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Here's an example:

```
var fd = new FormData();
var file = document.getElementById('image_src');
for (var i = 0; i < file.files.length; i++) {
    fd.append('_file', file.files[i]);
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', '/server_side_script', true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.send(fd);
```

Alternatively if your client browsers do not support the new HTML 5 File API or you cannot rely on it you could use some of the existing plugins such as [`jQuery.form`](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) or [`blueimp file upload`](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) which will test the capabilities of the client browser and if it doesn't support the HTML 5 File API will fallback to older techniques such as hidden iframes or Flash movies.

Comment: Someone Down Rated this Question. Was there a problem with my Question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use Filereader API. And write your php uploading files instead of i/upload.php.

input = document.getElementById("images") ;

```
        if(input != null){



            (function () {
                  input = document.getElementById("images<?=$rowArt['id']?>"), 
                   formdata = false;

                function showUploadedItem (source) {

                    if(document.getElementById("image-list<?=$rowArt['id']?>") != null)
                    {       

                        list = document.getElementById("image-list<?=$rowArt['id']?>"),
                        img  = document.createElement("img");
                        img.style.width = "80px";
                        img.style.height = "80px";
                        img.style.padding = "5px";
                        img.src = source;
                        list.appendChild(img);

                    }
                }   

                if (window.FormData) {
                    formdata = new FormData();
                    document.getElementById("btn<?=$rowArt['id']?>").style.display = "none";
                }

                input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
                    document.getElementById("response<?=$rowArt['id']?>").innerHTML = "Uploading . . ."
                    var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;

                    for ( ; i < len; i++ ) 
                    {
                        file = this.files[i];
                        if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) 
                        {
                            var myFileName =  file.name  ; 
                            if ( window.FileReader ) 
                            {
                                if (file){
                                    reader = new FileReader();

                                    reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
                                        if(file.size > 50000){
                                            alert('Your image is so large, please resize it to under 50k bytes.') ;
                                            return  ;
                                        }
                                        showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
                                    };
                                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                                }
                            }
                            if (formdata) 
                            {
                                formdata.append("images<?=$rowArt['id']?>[]", file);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (formdata) {


                        $.ajax({
                            url: "i/upload.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: formdata, 
                            processData: false,
                            contentType: false,
                            success: function (res) {
                                document.getElementById("response<?=$rowArt['id']?>").innerHTML = res; 
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }, false);
            }());
    }
```